# production.ERROR: exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException'

Tags: ssl, laravel-5

i have Error in this part somoene explain to me

```
 $error = isset($connectionErrors[$easy->errno])
        ? new ConnectException($message, $easy->request, null, $ctx)
        : new RequestException($message, $easy->request, $easy->response, null, $ctx);

    return new RejectedPromise($error);
}
```

Comment: See [ask]. What are you trying to do, what have you tried, and what results did you get? An error in the title is not clear enough.

Comment: Post all the details about the error you are getting. You posted the Guzzle library code, what is important is where YOUR code uses Guzzle and triggers the error